# Is there a way to override this already existing function?

Tags: python

What I want to specifically know is if there is a way to customize a piece of code already running by certain software.

I'll explain quickly the process of this software. When opening, of course there's all those pieces of codes being loaded, mostly divised in two entities, UI and Core, mostly because it will eventually be able to work without an interface (which is not the case right now, but that's not my point here).
So the soft is structure mostly like this:

```
software/
    core/
        some_functions.py
    ui/
        function_a.py
            class processUIBase(inheritanceUI):
                def __init__(blabla):
                    code = foo
                def method(self):
                    print "hello world"
                def createWidget(self):
                    widget = QLabel('Widget setting:')
                    layout.addWidget(widget)
                    return widget
        function_b.py
        [...]
```

Then comes in the plugins. There's a folder the software checks to bring the plugins, which works in a similar fashion (core/Ui).

```
/home/.software/
    Startup/  (What is loaded as plugins with the core)
        __init__.py
        plugins_that_works_well.py
    StartupUI/ (What is loaded as plugins with the UI)
        __init__.py
        menu.py
```

Basically, all this works right now.

But what I'd like to know is if there's a way for me to make something in the plugins folder (so without touching the software's base scripts) to override, for example, the function 'createWidget', to add some new lines (eg: widget_b = QCheckbox, layout,addWidget(widget_b).

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: please about how to produce a [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to change the behavior of code you can't directly modify. One solution that's kind of risky, but which is possible to do, is to swap out the original version of the function/class in the module with your own version, such that your own version acts very similar.

Here, you might be able to make a subclass and reassign it:

```
from software.ui import function_a

# maintain a reference to the original version, so it doesn't get lost
_ProcessUIBase = function_a.ProcessUIBase

# make a new subclass that does what you want
class ProcessUICustom(_ProcessUIBase):
    # override the superclass's method
    def createWidget(self):
        # add the functionality you want
        self.widget_b = QCheckbox, layout,addWidget(widget_b)
        # then do the original functionality
        return super().createWidget()

# replace the original class with our new version
function_a.ProcessUIBase = ProcessUICustom
```

This change will reflect across the rest of the program (as soon as someone imports the module in which you do this) for anything else that tries to use `function_a.ProcessUIBase`. It won't affect any other programs that import the same library, and the change will revert as soon as the program finishes executing. Also, there are ways around it by using `importlib` to reload the original `function_a`, which will wipe away the change. But it might be what you're looking for in this case.

Note that, if something else in the main part of the program has *already* imported `ProcessUIBase` *directly* (i.e. not just the module it's in, but the actual class):

```
from software.ui.function_a import ProcessUIBase
```

then this won't affect the version that's already been imported.

In essence, this is like changing someone's address in a directory. You can misdirect new people who look for that person, but if someone else already knows where to find that person, they won't be fooled.